# Inject __userpurge

Tags: windows, code-injection

I'm trying to inject into function that in IDA is described like

```
int __userpurge sub<eax>(int a1<ecx>, int a2<edi>, int a3<esi>, int a4, int a5, int ArgList)
```

Here is my hook function

```
__declspec(naked) int func_hook()
{
__asm{
    push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push dword ptr[ebp + 0x0C] // a6
        push dword ptr[ebp + 0x08] // a5
        push dword ptr[ebp + 0x04] // a4
        push esi // a3
        push edi // a2
        push ecx // a1
        call my_func
        leave
        ret // note: __usercall is cdecl-like
    }
}
```

Here is my function that should be called instead of hooked one

```
int __stdcall my_func(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6){
    std::cout << "int my_func()!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Into **sub** I inject like into **stdcall**-function, but app crashes without printing my message when it calls it's **sub** function.
What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: If you use "std::cout << "int my_func()!" << endl;" instead does it still crash without printing the message?

Comment: Yep. Later will try to debug **sub** function and it's caller a little bit - maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

When I redirected output into file I've found that **my_func** is working and crashes were caused by other code. When I called **sub** using trampoine app still crashed. Little investigation showed that prologue of target function was in 3 instructions in 6 bytes instead of 5. So, copying just 5 bytes into trampoline I've destroyed third instruction and this caused crashes.